# Cmake GNUInstallDirs variables empty

Tags: cmake

When trying to compile my project using `cmake .`, variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` is empty and I have no idea why.

I'm trying to issue the following (on line 40):

```
install(TARGETS fpthread
    EXPORT fpthread_config
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

I get the following error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (install):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target
  "fpthread".
```

Issuing the following results in an empty string:

```
MESSAGE(STATUS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

I've tried both Cmake 3.5 (installed through package manager) and Cmake 3.11 (latest release, compiled from source).

Comment: Do you have before accessing the variables in your CMakeLists.txt a line `include(GNUInstallDirs)`? They are not included by default.

Comment:  ... that's it. Thought they were included by default. My bad!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reformulating my previous comment as answer:

To access variables from the GNUInstallDirs module you need to add

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt file. The module is not included by default.